# How to securely sync the time and date on the server based on the time and date of the client's browser?

Tags: javascript, shell

I have 2 scripts to sync the time and date on the server based on the time and date on the client's browser, the server is just a local openwrt server at home and it's not connected to the internet.
The first script is javascript named `date.js`:

```
function formatDate(date) {
  var month = date.getMonth()+1;
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var seconds = date.getSeconds();
  var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
  return date.getFullYear() + "-" + month + "-" + date.getDate() + "  " + strTime;
}
var d = new Date();
var e = formatDate(d);
function send_datetime(){
  var xmlhttpp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
  else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
          //alert(xmlhttp.responseText)
      }
    }
  xmlhttp.open("POST","/cgi-bin/date",true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xmlhttp.send("update="+e);
}
send_datetime();
```

To run the javascript above I do `<script src="date.js"></script>` and the second script is cgi shell script named `date`, this is the script that actually syncs the time and date on the server:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
if [ "$REQUEST_METHOD" = POST ]; then
            read -t 3 QUERY_STRING
            QUERY_STRING=$(echo $QUERY_STRING | sed 's/&/ /g') 
            QUERY_STRING=$(echo $QUERY_STRING | sed 's/%3A/:/g') 
            CMD=${QUERY_STRING##*=}
            if [ ${#CMD} -gt 10 ] && echo "$CMD" | egrep "^[0-9 :-]+$";then
                    date -s "$CMD" # THIS MUST BE RUN AS ROOT OR IT WON'T SYNC
                    exit 0
            fi
fi
#end of file
```

The problem is that I can't run `date` without root permission, as you can see the `date -s` needs to be run as root. How can I safely sync it without someone hacking into my server?.

Comment: do the router's normal http responses include a Date header?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to programming, what do you mean by that ?